# Python: How to set class vars to another class of the same type

Tags: python

Is there an easy way to set the properties of one class equal to another instance of the same class?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

def main():
    classOne = Foo(1,2)
    classTwo = Foo(3,4)


    # DESIRED:
    classOne = classTwo # How can I easily set the 'a' and 'b' of classOne = classTwo?

if __name__ = "__main__":
    main()
```

I know something like this will work:

```
classOne.a = classTwo.a
classOne.b = classTwo.b
```

But is there a better way to do this for classes with more variables?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) sounds like what you're looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
import copy
classOne = copy.deepcopy(classTwo)
```

Take a look at the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) on this. A deep copy will create a new class (which you're setting to `classOne`) instance which has all of the same property values as `classTwo`.

```
import copy

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

def main():
    classTwo = Foo(3,4)
    classOne = copy.deepcopy(classTwo)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!